# разница равенста переменных и объектов класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

можете объяснить начинающему, почему при приравнивании объектов класса значения передаются обеим объектам, а не только тому что после знака равенства.

```
class car:
    pass
car1= car()
car1.wheels=4
car2=car1
print(car1.wheels,car2.wheels)
car2.wheels=3
print(car1.wheels,car2.wheels)

4 4
3 3
```

приравнивая car2 к car1 и меняя свойство car2, меняется свойство car1

при этом с переменными это так не работает

```
x1=4
print(x1)
x2=5
print(x2)

x2=x1
print(x1,x2)
x2=1
print(x1,x2)

4
5
4 4
4 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что, переменные хранят не объекты, а ссылки на них, поэтому `car2 = car1` это копирование **ссылки** на объект, а не самого объекта.

Это легко проверить, запросив `id` объектов у переменных `car1` и `car2`:

```
class Car:
    pass

car1 = Car()
car1.wheels = 4
car2 = car1

print(hex(id(car1)))
print(hex(id(car2)))
```

Когда вы создаете `car`, будут создаваться новые объект и возвращаться ссылки на них, 5 разных объектов:

```
for i in range(5):
    car = Car()
    print(i, hex(id(car)))
```

---

Ваш код можно переписать так:

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, wheels):
        self.wheels = wheels

car1 = Car(wheels=4)
car2 = Car(wheels=3)
print(car1.wheels, car2.wheels)  # 4 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть такое понятие как мутабельность (`mutable`, `immutable`) типов данных.
Твой класс `car` изменяемый (`mutable`) тип данных. Получается, что `car2=car1` - это просто копирование ссылки на память в которой находится содержимое `car1`.
После этого получается у тебя 2 ссылки на один тот же объект.

Например, со строками так не получится, потому что это неизменяемый (`immutable`) тип данных в python. Пример:

```
s = 'hello world'
a = s
a = 'world hello'
print(a, s)
# >>> world hello hello world
```

Comment: В общем вопрос немного не о том. Ни экземпляры ни классы(типы) не изменяемы, к примеру можно изменить содержимое в списке, но сам объект списка останется тот же. Воот. С экземплярами то же, меняется только содержимое объекта но не сам объект `self`.